# Can we get raw google adwords data?

Tags: data-science, apn, google-ads-api, dbm

I am trying to fetch raw data from google Adwords but not able to find it.I am able to get group level data but in that case our all dimension and metrics doesnot fall under one group, so I m looking for raw data.Please help me if google Adwords provide raw data or not?

Comment: what do you mean by raw data?

Comment: Hi Vivek,
Thank u.
Actually our requirement  is to get the granular reports which is not possible through UI reports. 
For Ex. I want to pull out the report which contains Date, audience, city, placement. 
Through UI, it is not allowing me to get all this dimensions at a same time.  If I took audience, city will be grayed out (not available) 
Through scripts also, it is not possible for us as all these dimensions are in different different tables. (Nothing unique id or such for join)

So is there any way like raw logs or such where we can get data with all the required granularity

Comment: Did you ever find a way to access the raw data? I also need to get the cost for keyword + location + device and cannot get it out of their reports.